# golang: time.LoadLocation("Europe/Moscow") выдает ошибку, где я ошибся?

Tags: golang, datetime, location

Есть такой код:

```
func main() {
    fmt.Println(isWorkingHours())
}

func isWorkingHours() (bool, error) {
    location, err := time.LoadLocation("Europe/Moscow")
    if err != nil {
        return false, err
    }
    now := time.Now().In(location)
    if now.Weekday() == time.Sunday || now.Weekday() == time.Saturday {
        return false, nil
    }
    if now.Hour() < 10 || now.Hour() > 19 {
        return false, nil
    }
    return true, nil
}
```

Он работает в Playground https://go.dev/play/p/BMwcZynMbdn?v=goprev, но локально отдает `nil, unknown time zone Europe/Moscow`

Не могу понять почему?

Docker: golang:1.19-alpine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно было добавить `_ "time/tzdata"`

Comment: Напишите что это нужно в импорты добавить (`import _ "time/txtime"`).

Answer (score 0):

https://lalatron.hashnode.dev/a-story-about-go-docker-and-time-zones

> How to fix it? First, let's see where our Go app retrieves the time
> zone information from. Time to peek into the time package. You can
> find here info on all environments, but below you can check where the
> time zone info is in Unix systems.
>
> /src/time/zoneinfo_unix.go:21
>
> ```
> // Many systems use /usr/share/zoneinfo, Solaris 2 has
> // /usr/share/lib/zoneinfo, IRIX 6 has /usr/lib/locale/TZ.
> var zoneSources = []string{
>     "/usr/share/zoneinfo/",
>     "/usr/share/lib/zoneinfo/",
>     "/usr/lib/locale/TZ/",
>     runtime.GOROOT() + "/lib/time/zoneinfo.zip",
> }
> ```
>
> For this approach, there are two things to do to get the time zone
> info data available at runtime.
>
> Copy the time zone info from the build image Update the ZONEINFO
> environment variable with the correct path to the zoneinfo.zip file
>
> ```
> FROM golang:1.14-alpine
> WORKDIR /app
> ADD . .
> RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -o myapp
>
> FROM scratch
> COPY --from=0 /app/myapp .
> COPY --from=0 /usr/local/go/lib/time/zoneinfo.zip /
> ENV ZONEINFO=/zoneinfo.zip
> CMD ["/myapp"]
> ```